# new Function scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I've got a piece of code with a ReferenceError [here](http://repl.it/ziX/2)

or below:

```
function foo() {

    function bar() {
        console.log('bar');
    }

    var x = new Function('bar();');
    x();
}

foo(); // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

Is it possible to make this happen? I mean the bar function to exist inside the `new Function`

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept so I will accept the one with the most vote-ups after a few days. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Functions created with the Function constructor do not create closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope in which the Function constructor was called.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

So no, it isn't while using that approach.

Don't use the function constructor. It is inefficient, and converting strings to code is [fraught with problems](https://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil).

```js
function foo() {

    function bar() {
        alert('bar');
    }

    function x() {
      bar();
    }
    x();
}

foo();
```

Comment: The thing is that bar is defined/coded by me but the user has to use it. The user inputs to a code editor and executes.

Comment: So use `eval` if you must take that approach.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to use `eval` instead of `new Function`:

```js
function foo() {

    function bar() {
        console.log('bar');
    }

    eval('x = function() { bar(); }');
    x();
}

foo(); // works fine.
```

Comment: I tried this but there is a conflict with the "use strict" inside the file I'm coding. Of course I can remove the strict mode so I think that's the only way.

Comment: You might want to declare `x` if you don't want a global var.

Comment: The whole point is to execute the function after eval or after new Function in order to catch the error with the line number.